# Trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have table `"Candidates"` with `id` (primary key) and `application_counter`
and table `"Applications"` with foreign key (`candidate_id`). I want `application_counter` to be modified each time Application is added or removed (or modified by changing `candidate_id`).

All I can do is to write:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
ON "Applications" FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcname ( arguments )
```

And the question is How can I write this trigger?

Synopsis from page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER } { event [ OR ... ] }
ON table [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcname ( arguments )
```

Comment: Ok, and what's the question? By the way, a trigger function can't accept arguments, check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a view, `INNER JOIN` the two tables, and count the rows in the `applications` table. (See `COUNT()`.) Triggers can be disabled; that view will always give you the right answer.

(Later . . .)

I understand you want to limit a candidate's rows in the table "applications" to 3 or less. In that case, I think it's best to use a `CHECK()` constraint on "applications" rather than the combination of a trigger on "applications" and a `CHECK()` constraint on "candidates".

To do that in PostgreSQL, you have to use a function, and call the function from the `CHECK()`. (As far as I know. You still can't execute arbitrary `SELECT` statements in `CHECK()` constraints, right?) So, you'd create this function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION num_applications(cand_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 

  DECLARE 
    n integer; 
  BEGIN 
    select count(*) 
    into n 
    from applications
    where (candidate_id = cand_id);

    return n; 
  END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then you'd add a CHECK() constraint to the table 'applications'.

```
ALTER TABLE applications
  ADD CONSTRAINT max_of_three CHECK (num_applications(candidate_id) < 3);
```

"< 3" because the `CHECK()` constraint is evaluated before adding a row. It's probably worth testing to see how this behaves with deferred constraints. If I have time later, I'll do that.

Comment: +1 a trigger seems to be overkill here (unless it is for training purposes)

Comment: I need triger because there is CHECK condition on `application_counter` that states that each candidate can post max 3 applications.

Comment: You could also use a SELECT count() in the trigger... would be fast also if there is a useful index on candidate_id.

Comment: What do you mean by 'useful'?

Comment: @Miko Kronn: In that case, I'd rather use a CHECK() constraint on the table `Applications`. I'll edit my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Sorry about that. Trimmed too much. I corrected it above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TRIGGER myname AFTER INSERT, DELETE OR UPDATE 
ON table applications
EXECUTE PROCEDURE myfunc();

CREATE FUNCTION myfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP != 'DELETE' THEN
        update candicate set application_count = application_count + 1 where id = new.candidate_id;
    END IF;
    IF TG_OP != 'INSERT' THEN
        update candicate set application_count = application_count + 1 where id = old.candidate_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

I hope you get the idea... works now also with updated candidate_id's.

Comment: How can I write this function to do what I want? I mean, how can I get id of "Candidates" being affected. There can be one (INSERT or DELETE) or two (UPDATE).

Comment: Inside "myFunc()", for the Insert side, "Update candidates set counter = counter + 1 where id = new.candidate_id".  For the delete trigger, refer to "old.candidate.id".  Updates don't do anything unless it is possible to change the candidate_id field, in which case you decrement from old and increment new.

Comment: This might be a new question but... How can I prevent update on `candidate_id` column?

Comment: Raise an exception in the trigger, if `old.candiate_id is distinct from new.candidate_id`